# Creating query in access to compare fields

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with an Access query - I work in a mailing house and sometimes the address data that we receive has repeating elements across fields, for example the field add1 may contain "123 Sample Street City" and add2 may contain "City".

I wrote this query to isolate those records where this repeating happens:

```
select * from working where right(add1,len(add2))=add2
```

This works fine in one table, but in another table I get the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Both the fields in both tables are short text, so I can't understand why it works for one table and not for another.

Thank you all for any insight or guidance.

Regards,

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

There is probably inconsistency in data types. For example you may compare string and integer. In order to prevent such cases and considering the fact that you use MS Access I would suggest to use Str function

```
select * from working where right(TRIM(Str(add1)),len(TRIM(Str(add2))))=TRIM(Str(add2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Igor. I was hoping that this would work but sadly not. I still get the same error and interestingly, the table that was working before now doesn't - showing the same error.

Comment: Let me guess... You might have either integer or float (or any other weird stuff) in both tables and now when you try to enforce conversion to string you get an error message. Try to add TRIM as well

Comment: Thanks Igor. I see what you're getting at, but it still makes no difference I'm afraid. I can create a new table with two simple short text fields and the query as I originally posted works fine. It's just this one table where it doesn't work. I've pasted a few records from the problem table into a new table and that works, so maybe it's just a dodgy record somewhere. Maybe I'll try splitting the file in half and isolate the bad record(s) that way.

Comment: Update: the records that are causing the query to fail are those where there is no entry in add2. I tried to account for this by adding another clause to the query:
select * from [copy of working not working2] where right(add1,len(add2))=add2 and len(add2)>0
but still no joy.

Comment: @MalcolmWhild you can sort this out with use of IsNull function: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php

Comment: Hi Igor,
Thanks so much for your help. I didn't really understand how to use the isNull function because I can't see how to write multiline statements in access, but I did have success with the following query:

select * from [copy of working2] WHERE iif(isnull(add2),null,right(add1,len(add2))=add2)

so the conditional IIF() statement stops the data type mismatch because the null fields are never evaluated

Next step is to remove those duplicates from the end of add1.

Regards,

Malcolm

Comment: Malcolm, you are welcome. IsNull is a pretty simple function. You give it a value and returns TRUE or FALSE. IsNull("Whatever") returns FALSE, IsNull(12) returns FALSE, IsNull() returns TRUE

Comment: The other option is NZ(). This function gets value and convert it to something else if the value is null. Let's say a= null, then NZ(a, 0) = 0, or NZ(a, "The value is null") = "The value is null". If a=12, then NZ(a, 0) = 12